# How to have a JButton that moves as I scroll on the frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I have a Panel which I have made scrollable in my frame.
What I need is to add a button that stays fixed in the lower right corner even when I scroll.
I'm new to Java Swing so would appreciate all and any help that I can get.

```
mainPanel = new SimulationPanel(); //class SimulationPanel extends JPanel

//making mainPanel scrollable
mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(((int)(WIDTH*1.2)), HEIGHT));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
scrollPane.setViewportView(mainPanel);

// Settings for JFrame
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame = new JFrame("Warehouse Simulator");
frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);
frame.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
frame.setResizable(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a BoxLayout. Add another panel (metaPanel) in which your first put your scrollingPanel, and then you add a button. Instead of usgin scrollingPanel as contentPane, you use metaPanel. Example (the example works, but you need to modify it to make the interface look nice):

```
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(mainPanel);

    JPanel metaPanel = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout boxlayout = new BoxLayout(metaPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    metaPanel.setLayout(boxlayout);
    metaPanel.add(scrollPane);
    metaPanel.add(new JButton("button"));

    // Settings for JFrame
    frame = new JFrame("Warehouse Simulator");
    frame.setContentPane(metaPanel); // Put metaPanel here
    frame.setSize(500, 300);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @GauravAgarwal *What I need is to add a button that stays fixed in the lower right corner* - the button isn't displayed in the lower right corner.

Comment: Then you need to add yet another panel, this time between metaPanel and JButton. Choose a Layout that allows you to put the button in the center of the panel. Working with Swing, you need to get used to fairly deep structures of panels.

Comment: @camickr I figured that part on my own once going through this solution.

Comment: @camickr @Stenfan I did like this:
```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
buttonPanel.add(buttonPlus);
metaPanel.add(buttonPanel);
```

Comment: @GauravAgarwal *I figured that part on my own* - well that solution was already given to you in the other answer. However, I suspect it still doesn't work properly. When you resize the height of the frame. the extra space will be allocated to both panels. that you add to the "metaPanel". So the button will remain at the right, but it will not be at the bottom.

Comment: I have in fact been able to add another button right there as I wanted. It looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/0mNn8Yi

Cant share the code unfortunately -

Comment: @GauravAgarwal, didn't say you couldn't. Again, the way the BoxLayout works is that when you have two panels and you resize the height of the frame, the extra height will be added to both panels. In you original question you implied you have a panel and a button. In this standard design the button should remain at is fixed position and the panel should grow/shrink as the frame size is change. In this situation, it is not best to use a BoxLayout for the reason I gave above. Our answers can only be provided based on the information given.

Comment: @camickr I understand it better now. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

I would use nested panels with the outer one be with `BorderLayout`. Then one with `FlowLayout` and align `FlowLayout.RIGHT` and the button inside it.

```
public class Example extends JFrame {
    public Example() {
        super("");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10000, 0);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("button");

        JPanel panelWithButton = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        panelWithButton.add(button);
        add(panelWithButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        pack();
        setSize(600, 600);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Example().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: `JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10000, 0);` - the rows/columns value should be  realistic numbers like (20, 80) then you just pack() the frame and get rid of the setSize(…) statement. The text area will then be sized to hold 20 lines of data and 80 "W" characters.

Comment: @camickr (+1) 20 rows will not be vertically scrollable. I wanted to make sure that textarea will require scrolling, hence I used a high random row number. I know that `pack();` and `setSize` *should* not be together, but mehh....this is "off topic".